# Chebyshev Polynomials - verifying

Tags: real-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials

How can I show the following properties of Chebyshev polynomials if I am only given the recursion formula and $$T_0(x)=1 \\ T_1(x)=x \\ T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$$

Verify

$$T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta)\\
|T_n(x)| \le 1$$

Second one can easily be verified, but stuck on the first one.

Comment: What does induction tell you?

Comment: i would try Induction with respect to $n$

Comment: or use Google there are many different proofs known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

By direct substitution,

$$T_{n+1}(\cos\theta)=2\cos\theta\,T_n(\cos\theta)-T_{n-1}(\cos\theta)$$

becomes

$$\cos(n+1)\theta=2\cos\theta\cos n\theta-\cos(n-1)\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

- Use induction on $n$.
- The cases for $T_0$ and $T_1$ are direct.
- Use the product to sum formula (trig identity) for the inductive case.